# Can I stay connected via NFC without any data transfer?

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef

I wish to connect two android devices on NFC without any data transfer and stay connected as long as the devices are separated.
I have been investigating ways but I cannot think of any way to make this possible.

Please give advice if you have an idea and a detailed explanation of how I can achieve this would be really appreciated.
Plus, if this is possible, what do I need to do about the NDEF record?

I'll wait for your response.

Answer (score -2):

as you may now, `NFC` is for closed range distance and for `p2p` exchange of data, it doesn't need a connection, it just send desired data(`NDEF` Transfer data like URLs, contacts, etc or File Transfer data like images, videos, etc) into `NFC` and the other device receive it(it is important to consider that two devices must turn on NFC's and be close to each other and not be locked!).

So in my opinion, it is not possible to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea, Mehran.

Comment: that's not true, the devices know when they stay close to each other, and consider themselves connected.